# How to capture SoapRequest.xml and SoapResponse.xml

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have created a Java Webservice(first  .WSDL file,then wsdl2Java)using Axis2 stack sucessfully.If I'm using Axis2 stack,it'll creates all the Java beans stuff.

I have written a Webservice Client using Stubs generated from the WSDL in pure Java by creating Request Object ( in Java) and in the Response I got java object.

But my requirement is that, I need to get the .XML format for the both.

Please let me know how can I capture actual SoapRequest.xml file and the SoapResponse.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to intercept http traffic.

Comment: Could you provide any extra info on how to intercept the traffic if it's encrypted yet coming from the machine you are on?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do in Java. But check if [SOAP tracer by MS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en) can be used ? It intercepts the SOAP request and response and show in its editor.

Answer (score 0):

Axis comes with a utility called [tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#AppendixUsingTheAxisTCPMonitorTcpmon), which is designed for this. It acts as a proxy, and shows the request/response pairs as you issue/receive them. Just run:

```
java org.apache.axis.utils.tcpmon [listenPort targetHost targetPort]
```

and redirect the SOAP requests via this. You'll get a UI showing each request and the corresponding response.